# hook faile in laravel use command line

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to use the hook to update my code, run in macos success, centos fail
:

```
public function pull() {
      $command = "cd /var/www/laravel && git pull origin master";
      $last_line = system($command, $retval);
       print_r($last_line);
       print_r($retval);
       exit();
}
```

if the `$command = "cd /var/www/laravel && pwd"`, all success. very confused.

Comment: write permissions?

Comment: I try ``$command = "cd /var/www/ && echo \"passwd\" | sudo echo abc > abc.text";``. Does not work.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I am a novice, I do not know how to view the wrong message. I only know that the function return 1, not 0. @kerbholz

Comment: Take a look at [What does the linux pipe symbol “|” do?](https://superuser.com/questions/756158/what-does-the-linux-pipe-symbol-do)

Comment: Also, try `$command = "cd /var/www/laravel && git pull origin master 2>&1";`, note `2>&1` at the end. You can read more about [what does “ 2>&1 ” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)

Comment: This will give you error messages from terminal

Comment: I use ``$command = "cd /var/www/laravel && git pull origin master 2>&1"``, get the error ``error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied``. @ljubadr

Comment: Look into this blog post - [Git pull from a php script, not so simple.](https://jondavidjohn.com/git-pull-from-a-php-script-not-so-simple/), could guide you into right direction

Comment: Thank you.This article is great.@ljubadr